# A function in ElevatedButton() onPressed: property not working when the parent Column() is a child of AlertDialog()

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile-development

There is a problem in my code, the function addCu() in ElevatedButton() onPressed: property not adding items to ListVew.Builder() when the parent Column() is a child of AlertDialog()

Here's the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../constants.dart';
import '../models/currencies.dart';

class AddCurrency extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function addCu;

  const AddCurrency({
    super.key,
    required this.addCu,
  });

  @override
  State<AddCurrency> createState() => _AddCurrencyState();
}

class _AddCurrencyState extends State<AddCurrency> {


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    void addNewCurrency(String cuName, double cuPrice, double cuPercentage) {

      final newCu = Currencies(
        currencyName: cuName,
        currencyPrice: cuPrice,
        currencyPercent: cuPercentage,

      );

      setState(() {
        currenciesList.add(newCu);
      });

    }


    return FloatingActionButton(
      backgroundColor: Colors.pink,
      child: const Icon(Icons.notification_add),
      onPressed: () => showDialog(context: context, builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
        content: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            TextFormFieldSource(
              data: 'Add Currency Name',
              controller: currencyNameController,
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: kDefaultPadding,
            ),
            TextFormFieldSource(
              data: 'Add Currency Price',
              controller: currencyPriceController,
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: kDefaultPadding,
            ),
            TextFormFieldSource(
              data: 'Add Currency Percentage',
              controller: currencyPercentController,
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: kDefaultPadding,
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                widget.addCu(
                  currencyNameController.text,
                  double.parse(currencyPriceController.text),
                  double.parse(currencyPercentController.text),
                );
                addNewCurrency;
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
              child: const Text('Add currency now!'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),),
    );
  }
}
```

Note that, the function works and adding items when removing FloatingActionButton() and showDialog() and AlertDialog().

And in the following code, why we need to use an empty list "listOfCurrencies" in ListVew.Builder() instead of the list that we want to add items to it "currenciesList", which is in the dart file that contains the model and has at least one object instance in it?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../constants.dart';
import '../models/currencies.dart';

class CurrencyList extends StatelessWidget {

  final List<Currencies> listOfCurrencies;

  const CurrencyList({Key? key, required this.listOfCurrencies}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      height: 300,
      child: ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: listOfCurrencies.length,
        itemBuilder: (context , index) => Card(
          color: Colors.white,
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
                height: 50,
                width: 50,
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.purple,
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    boxShadow: [
                      BoxShadow(
                        offset: Offset(0, 5),
                        blurRadius: 15,
                      ),
                    ]),
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    listOfCurrencies[index].currencyName!.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase(),
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 30,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),

              SizedBox(
                width: kDefaultPadding,
              ),

              Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    listOfCurrencies[index].currencyName!,

                    style: const TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,

                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: kDefaultPadding,
                  ),

                   Text(
                    '\$${listOfCurrencies[index].currencyPrice!}',
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: kDefaultPadding,
                  ),

                  Text(
                    '1 hour: ${listOfCurrencies[index].currencyPercent!}%',
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.red,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Where the experts go when one need them?!!!!

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are not actually calling the "**addNewCurrency**" function.  you need to call it like a regular function by using "**addNewCurrency()**" instead of just "**addNewCurrency**".

```
 ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: () {
    widget.addCu(
      currencyNameController.text,
      double.parse(currencyPriceController.text),
      double.parse(currencyPercentController.text),
    );
    addNewCurrency(
      currencyNameController.text,
      double.parse(currencyPriceController.text),
      double.parse(currencyPercentController.text),
    );
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
  },
  child: const Text('Add currency now!'),
),
```

Comment: Neither of the two functions works